# Destructor called twice causes crash

Tags: c++

I implemented a constructor that takes a string as argument, this causes the destructor to get called twice and then the program crashes (the program contains a raw pointer). I know that it has to do with the copy constructor that somehow gets called when this type of constructors are used. Below is a simple code that illustrates the problem.

I would appreciate your comments on how to fix the program to avoid it to crash. I need to use this kind of constructors.
I would like to understand why the copy constructor gets called. I didn't do any explicit assignment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class DebugClass
{
public:
    DebugClass(void) {
        data = NULL;
    }

    DebugClass(std::string str) {
        data = new double[2];
        data[0] = 1.0;
        data[1] = 2.0;
    }

    DebugClass(DebugClass const& other) {
        cout << "copy construction\n"; 
    }

    ~DebugClass(void) {
        if (data)
        {
            delete [] data;
            data = NULL;
        }
    }

    double* data;
};


int main()
{
    DebugClass obj = DebugClass("Folder");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `DebugClass obj("Folder");`?

Comment: One problem is that your copy constructor doesn't copy the object.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I would have thought the copy in `DebugClass obj = DebugClass("Folder");` would have been elided. Using direct initialization might solve the problem, but you should define a reasonable copy constructor. Regardless, this would be avoided by avoiding raw pointers for your member data.

Comment: I can't see any constructor or destructor code which contains the problem. You presented code is not helpful. Can you please provide the minimum code to reproduce the failure. So please remove unused parts like `DebugClass(void);` And as a hint: Please remove all `void` pseudo arguments, especially from destructor! It looks ugly and is old c syntax. It is still allowed but not useful.

Comment: Nor does your copy-ctor member-initialize `data` (which all three of your constructors should be doing, frankly). Your default and parameterized *assign* the member, but where possible (and it is in all these cases) prefer member-initialization).

Comment: Related reading ["rule of 3"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/3747990) and "rule of 5" or "rule of zero".

Comment: Your copy constructor generally should _copy_ the object, not just print a message.

Comment: @ crashmstr Yes. Thanks... This fixed the problem...

Comment: I added the copy constructor to track the crash...Do I need to define a copy constructor in the example above? Thanks

Comment: For me the provided code runs without problem.  I presume @TartanLlama is right that on certain architectures/compilers there is elision of the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your copy constructor leaves `data` uninitialized:

```
DebugClass::DebugClass(DebugClass const& other) 
{ 
    cout << "copy construction\n"; 
}
```

So any use of data from that point on will give undefined behaviour.

If you simply set `data` to `nullptr` there, then you should not get the double deletion. Though you probably really want to do some form of copying from `other`.

This line:

```
DebugClass obj = DebugClass("Folder");
```

results in the copy constructor being called as part of constructing `obj`.

If you instead did:

```
DebugClass obj("Folder");
```

then `obj` would be constructed with the normal constructor.

Comment: If I do  DebugClass obj = DebugClass("Folder"); What should I do to make it work .. It crahes even when I don't define a copy constructor

Comment: A copy constructor should make a copy of all the data in the object. In your case, you'd need to allocate a properly sized buffer assigned to `this->data` and then copy the contents of `other.data` into it.

Comment: @user3026374 I would recommend finding some tutorials on C++ constructors and reading about the rule of 3, rule of 5, rule of 0. It should all be clearer have read up around those areas.

Answer (score 1):

```
DebugClass obj = DebugClass("Folder");
```

The rhs creates a nameless object and being assigned to obj which is a another new object creation, hence calling the copy constructor.

Your statement is equivalent to

```
DebugClass obj1;
DebugClass obj2 = obj1; // here copy-ctor gets invoked
```

And for the second part ...although you have define a copy-ctor, it is hardly benefits your program, because you did nothing with the pointer data member, which is left uninitialized. That leads to undefined behavior.

Though I am not aware of your intention about the class DebugClass, but in a simpler way it can be defined with another data member say `array_size` and you ctors can be as given below.

```
    DebugClass(void):array_size(0) {
    data = NULL;
}

DebugClass(std::string str, size_t aSize):array_size(aSize)
{
    if(array_size)
    {
       data = new double[array_size];
       data[0] = 1.0;
       data[1] = 2.0;
    }
}

DebugClass(DebugClass const& other):array_size(other.array_size)
{
    cout << "copy construction\n"; 
    if(array_size)
    {
       data = new double[array_size];
       for(int i=0; i<array_size; i++)
           data[i] = other.data[i];
    }
}
```

Hope this clarifies.